# Alexa - build custom slot for addresses

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I am creating in which a user can say an address (for further processing). An address can be anything from "New York" to "123 First Avenue Washington" to "Seattle Harbor". Basically like something you can enter at Google Maps - it will recognize more or less everything :)

So now of course comes the problem on how to create a custom slot for this? LITERAL is deprecated PLUS I am working on a German language skill.

Should I actually try to fill the 50,000 lines I got available for a custom skill with as many enumerations of addresses as I can come up with? I'm afraid that even if I go down that road, Alexa will still try to map any input that's not in that list to one that is - and thereby rendering my skill a bit mood :(

Thanks for any advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suggest, using a custom slot with 50K sample addresses wouldn't really work.  Something as complicated as an address really needs a built-in slot type, and there is one for US skills:

https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/built-in-intent-ref/slot-type-reference#postaladdress

But you noted that you are targeting a German language skill and as far as I know there isn't a German language or address version of the above built-in slot yet.

The fact that they have done it for US suggests that they will add it for Germany at some point, but counting on that is risky, of course, so you are in a difficult position.  In the mean-time I would suggest you go to the [feature request space](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/spaces/185/index.html) and add a request for a German version of the above:

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Didn't know that this already exists form English. I'll try the request then.